# Python Counting Same Values For Specific Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If i have a dataframe;

```
      A       B       C      D
1     1       2       2      1
2     1       1       2      1
3     3       1       0      1
4     2       4       4      4
```

I want to make addition B and C columns and counting whether or not the same values with D columns. Desired output is;

```
          A       B       C     B+C      D
    1     1       2       2      4       1
    2     1       1       2      3       1
    3     3       1       0      1       1
    4     2       4       4      8       4 

There are 3 different values compare the "B+C" and "D".
```

Could you please help me about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
df.B.add(df.C).ne(df.D).sum()
# 3
```

---

If you need to add the column:

```
df['B+C'] = df.B.add(df.C)
diff = df['B+C'].ne(df.D).sum()
print(f'There are {diff} different values compare the "B+C" and "D"')
#There are 3 different values compare the "B+C" and "D"
```

Comment: Hi @yatu, thanks for the asnwer. One more thing; if i want to substract the C from B, what should i use the instead .add() method?

Comment: @Salih use the `sub` method.  Please accept this answer and consider upvoting it.

Comment: you can also use the (likely) familiar syntax `((df.B + df.C) != df.D).sum()`, with the only cost of adding some more parenthesis

Answer (score 1):

```
df.insert(3,'B+C', df['B']+df['C'])
3 is the index
df.head()

    A   B   C   B+C D
0   1   2   2   4   1
1   1   1   2   3   1
2   3   1   0   1   1
3   2   4   4   8   4
```

After that you can follow the steps of @yatu

```
df['B+C'].ne(df['D'])
0     True
1     True
2    False
3     True dtype: bool

df['B+C'].ne(df['D']).sum()
 3
```